Prove for any $a,b,c \in G$, $[ab,c]=a[b,c]a^{-1}[a,c]$.
Let $G$ be a group and $a,b \in G$. Denote the commutator $aba^{-1}b^{-1} \in G$ by $[a,b]$. Prove for any $a,b,c \in G$, $[ab,c]=a[b,c]a^{-1}[a,c]$.
This is a problem from Hungerford, my attempt is below. I believe it to be correct.

Let $a,b,c\in G$. We show $[ab,c]=a[b,c]a^{-1}[a,c]$.
$[ab,c] = abc(ab)^{-1}c^{-1} = abcb^{-1}a^{-1}c^{-1} = abcb^{-1}c^{-1}ca^{-1}c^{-1}= a[b,c]ca^{-1}c^{-1} = a[b,c]a^{-1}aca^{-1}c^{-1} = a[b,c]a^{-1}[a,c].$
Hence the proof is complete.

This looks correct.

@Bowei Tang There is no reason for your edit. It even made the display worse on small devices. If the OP wanted to display one formula per line, accept it and just keep it.

@MartinBrandenburg Sorry about that, I rolled it back. (but in my device, the last few characters are obscured)
